# Access issue when uploading file to CloudBlockBlob - Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I had to upgrade from Windows Azure 1.7 to 2.1. The only change in code I had

blob.UploadFromFile(tempImage);
to
blob.UploadFromFile(tempImage,FileMode.CreateNew);

However I am getting the following error: "Combining FileMode: CreateNew with FileAccess: Read is invalid."

Here is my code below (I added the  "blob.OpenWrite();" just to try). Any ideas why I am getting this error?

```
  string blobUri;

        /*var acct = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("ImagesConnectionString");*/

        var setting = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ImagesConnectionString");
         var acct = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(setting);

        var blobClient = acct.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("ContainerName")); //.GetContainerReference("ContainerName");
        container.CreateIfNotExists(); //CreateIfNotExist

        var perms = container.GetPermissions();

        //upload blob image
        LocalResource local = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("tempImages");
        string tempSlideImage = local.RootPath + mySlideName;
        myImage.Save(tempSlideImage);            

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(myImageName);
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; //photoToLoad.PostedFile.ContentType; //blob.Properties.ContentType = photoToLoad.PostedFile.ContentType;

        blobClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 3;
        blob.OpenWrite(); //this was added after the migration
        blob.UploadFromFile(tempImage,FileMode.CreateNew); //.UploadFile //blob.UploadFromStream(photoToLoad.FileContent);
        blobUri = blob.Uri.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kwill said will work, however I solved like this:

```
 using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(tempSlideImage))
        {
            blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }
```

Answer (score 17):

The 2nd parameter to UploadFromFile (the FileMode) is referring to how you want to open the file on your local machine, not what you want to do with the blob in Azure storage.  So to fix you can:

Change

```
blob.UploadFromFile(tempImage,FileMode.CreateNew);
```

to

```
blob.UploadFromFile(tempImage,FileMode.Open);
```

Also, what is tempImage?  You either left out that portion of the code, or it should be tempSlideImage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are correct that it is tempslideimage. I actually solved it by using a stream

Comment: thanks! This got me as well. It makes absolutely no sense that you have to specify the FileMode parameter - when would I ever want it to use anything but FileMode.Read - I can think of only the case where I just want to upload an empty file, then I can tell it to CreateNew

Comment: UPDATE: Azure SDK 2.7 with .NET 4.5.1 the following code works blob.UploadFromFile(tempImage,FileMode.Open);

Comment: @kwill can you check this answer for errors? I don't believe the `FileMode` enum has ever had a `.Read` member; did you mean `FileMode.Open`? `FileAccess` is the enum that has `.Read`

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard, I think you are right.  I probably would have tested the code before posting, but this was 5 years go so I don't remember now :).  I have updated the answer to FileMode.Open.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the server incorrectly identifies the filename of the HttpPostedFileBase. Thus, load the inputstream, directly.

```
  HttpPostedFileBase file

   CloudBlockBlob blob;
    .......

   using (var fileStream = file.InputStream)
    {
        blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    }
```